# Avoiding repeating code when assigning pointer addresses based on branch

Tags: c, clean-code, pointers, switch-statement

I have the following code in C that reads data off a char array and makes decisions on what variables should some pointers point to.

```
char preset1[20];
char preset1Name[20];
int preset1Temp;
int preset1ETemp;
char preset2[20];
char preset2Name[20];
int preset2Temp;
int preset2ETemp;
char preset3[20];
char preset3Name[20];
int preset3Temp;
int preset3ETemp;

void foo(unsigned char *inputCmd, char *preset, char *name, int *startTemp, int *eTemp){
    switch (inputCmd[3]){ //inputCmd should be "XXX1", "XXX2" or "XXX3"
    case '1':
        preset = preset1;
        name = preset1Name; 
        startTemp = &preset1Temp;
        eTemp = &preset1ETemp;
        break;
    case '2':
        preset = preset2;
        name = preset2Name;
        startTemp = &preset2Temp;
        eTemp = &preset2ETemp;
        break;
    case '3':
        preset = preset3;
        name = preset3Name;
        startTemp = &preset3Temp;
        eTemp = &preset3ETemp;
        break;
    default:
        preset = preset1;
        name = preset1Name;
        startTemp = &preset1Temp;
        eTemp = &preset1ETemp;
    }
}
```

My current function only requires 2 char arrays and 2 int pointers to assign, as well as only having 3 branches, so it is relatively clean. However, there is a lot of code that basically does the same thing just slightly differently.

```
preset = preset1;
name = preset1Name;
startTemp = &preset1Temp;
eTemp = &preset1ETemp;
```

Especially if the function has more items to assign (say, 30-40 objects like preset1) or more branches, the duplication of code might cause problems with human error (such as accidentally assigning the wrong address), and I am wondering what are some methods to avoid that.

The method of avoiding code repeat I thought of so far would be:

```
char presetX[3][20];
char presetXName[3][20];
int presetXTemp[3];
int presetXETemp[3];

void foo(unsigned char *inputCmd, char *preset, char *name, int *startTemp, int *eTemp){
    int selector = 0;
    switch (inputCmd[3]){ //inputCmd should be "XXX1", "XXX2" or "XXX3"
    case '1':
        selector = 0;
        break;
    case '2':
        selector = 1;
        break;
    case '3':
        selector = 2;
        break;
    default:
        selector = 0;
    }
    preset = presetX[selector];
    name = presetXName;
    startTemp = &presetXTemp + selector * sizeof(presetXTemp[0]);
    eTemp = &presetXETemp + * sizeof(presetXETemp[0]);
}
```

But I am wondering whether there are other methods of reducing code repeat. Specifically, whether there is a method of avoiding code repeat without converting the external variables (like preset1, preset1Temp) into arrays.

Please let me know if more information or more research on my end is required, as well as if the question needs more clarity.

Comment: It seems like you might want a `struct preset { char data[20]; char name[10]; int startTemp; int eTemp;};`

Answer (score 1):

As @amon suggests, you could use a `struct` here to model the presets; then you can have an array of preset structs and then your second snippet of code can just do `presets[selector].<name/temp/etc`